# Laravel Dropzone Invalid Argument

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, dropzone.js

i get a invalid argument in my controller when i post my form including images via dropzone.js. I set the param name to files and it is working without dropzone. i can't figure out why i get a invalid argument error while using dropzone. can anyone help?

Script

```
  <script>

            Dropzone.options.dropkicks = { 
              autoProcessQueue: false,
              uploadMultiple: true,
              parallelUploads: 100,
              paramName: "files",
              maxFiles: 100

            }
            var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropkicks", { url: "item-create-post"});

</script>
```

Controller

```
foreach(Input::file('files') as $file) {

            $filename = time(). $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $uploadflag = $file->move('uploads', $filename);

            if($uploadflag) {
                $uploadedfiles[] = $filename;

                $item_image = ItemImage::create(
                    array(
                        'item_id'   => $item->id,
                        'image'     => $filename
                    )
                );
            }

        }
```

Dropzone

```
            <div class="dropzone" id="dropkicks"></div>
```

Comment: Could you post the complete error message?

Comment: not enough reputation to post images :(

ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: So you have a form around that `#dropkicks` div which you submit with other information along side the image files?

Comment: yes, some basic input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this unless you mess with the source code of `dropzone.js`. That's because the plugin is meant to be used to upload files asynchronously. With a couple of changes in dropzone.js though, you can get it to work (I'm assuming you're using the [latest version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/enyo/dropzone/master/downloads/dropzone.js)).

Find this line:

```
document.body.appendChild(_this.hiddenFileInput);
```

And replace it with this:

```
_this.hiddenFileInput.setAttribute("name", "files[]");
_this.element.appendChild(_this.hiddenFileInput);
```

---

Also find this line:

```
return setupHiddenFileInput();
```

And comment it out:

```
// return setupHiddenFileInput();
```

---

You form should look something like this:

```
<!-- Make sure you add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form tag -->
<form action="/item-create-post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- some form fields... -->
    <div class="dropzone" id="dropkicks"></div>
    <!-- maybe some more form fields... -->
    <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

Your script part should also look like this:

```
Dropzone.options.dropkicks = { 
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    paramName: "files",
    maxFiles: 100,
    // This URL is not really used in your case but it's needed
    // because the plugin won't attach itself without one specified
    url: '#'
}
```

Also remove this line from your script because it's not needed. The dropzone will automatically be attached to any elements with the class "dropzone":

<s>`var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropkicks", { url: "item-create-post"});`</s>

Answer (score 0):

Place the script right below where you've included main dropzone.js.